# получение публичного ключа yandex api

Tags: python, yandex-disk

Как можно получить primary key для доступа к папке yandex disk. В библиотеки yadisk есть метод publish, который делает папку публичной. Но он не возвращает не ключа на нее, не ссылки, какой метод позволит ее получить.

**Дополнение к вопросу**

вот код, который использую для создания папки

```
y = yadisk.YaDisk(token="мой токен") 
y.mkdir("/test-dir")
y.publish('/test-dir')
respons = requests.get(url= 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/resources ? path= /test-dir', params=False)
print(respons.json())
```

а вот что мне выводит:

```
{'message': 'Ресурс не найден.', 'description': 'Not Found', 'error': 'NotFoundError'}
```

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/disk/api/reference/meta.html

Comment: @Alexey Ten если посмотреть документацию то там используется ключ, который я и пытаюсь получить

Comment: Нет, там используется path, который у вас есть

Comment: @Alexey Ten а этот при любом указанном пути выдает сообщение о том, что ресурс на найден. И даже если ты только что создал эту папку

Comment: @Alexey Ten и если вы знаете ответ, то почему бы его не предложить. Директория называется /test-dir

Comment: Покажите как вы публикуете папку

Comment: @Alexey Ten добавил информацию с кодом

Comment: Так у вас библиотека есть. Зачем лезть напрямую в API? Вот же https://yadisk.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/docs.html#yadisk.YaDisk.get_meta

Comment: Зачем у вас лишние пробелы в `url=`? Не знаю влияет ли это, но вполне может.